# How can I redirect the standard output of an SSH Session into a file?

Tags: ssh, terminal, cpu, redirection

I want to collect CPU information from a cisco device via SSH, but i want to save the info into a file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `ssh user@host 2>&1 | tee ssh-session.log`